# I dont understand what I typed wrong on def function but it is all correct on Python?

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python and I have problem with def function which I dont know what is the problem?
I am thinking to convert inches to centimeters or opposite,heres the code and error:

```
def centimeters_to_inches(inches):
    inches = centimeters / 2.54
    return(inches)

print(centimeters_to_inches(100))
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfunction.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(centimeters_to_inches(100))
  File "myfunction.py", line 2, in centimeters_to_inches
    inches = centimeters / 2.54
NameError: name 'centimeters' is not defined
```

Comment: Where would the variable called `centimeters` come from?

Comment: `def centimeters_to_inches(centimeters):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there is a mistake in the parameter I guess. The parameter of the function should be `centimeters` while the return value is `inches` since it aims to convert centimeters to inches.

```py
def centimeters_to_inches(centimeters):
    inches = centimeters / 2.54
    return inches

print(centimeters_to_inches(100))
```

*The error says that you are using a variable called `centimeters` that is not defined since it has not been declared (nor as variable nor as a parameter).*

Comment: @mihael153 the parameter shall be `centimeters` and not `inches` `centimeters_to_inches(centimeters)` since it's the return value. Please double check my answer.